# Resuming playback on XBMC only seems to work from a certain point onwards

Tags: raspbmc, video, kodi

I've noticed that when I stop a video near the beginning, it sometimes doesn't let you resume playback if you've stopped a video within a certain time period, but I can't seem to find any setting that lets you tweak how long this time period is. Does anyone know how to adjust this time frame in which resuming playback isn't available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You need to create an `advancedsettings.xml` file in `~/.xbmc/userdata/` if you don't have one already, and add the `ignoresecondsatstart` setting:

```
<advancedsettings>                                                                                                                                                                                          
  <video>                                                                       
    <ignoresecondsatstart>15</ignoresecondsatstart>
  </video>                                                                      
</advancedsettings>
```

It appears as though the default is 180 seconds.

Source: http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=advancedsettings.xml#.3Cvideo.3E